# How to filter an array of objects into a single object and organised by its keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm trying to filter an array of objects and return a single object, organised by the keys `continents`, `countries` and `cities` and we place those objects in the correct key.

```
const data = [{
  location: [{
      name: 'Africa',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Angola',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Luanda',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}, {
  location: [{
      name: 'Europe',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Italy',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Rome',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}, {
  location: [{
      name: 'Europe',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Spain',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Valencia',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}]
```

It should  result in:

```
{

  Africa: {
    countries: {
      Angola: {
        cities: {
          Luanda: {
            values: []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  Europe: {
    countries: {
      Italy: {
        cities: {
          Rome: {
            values: []
          }
        }
      },
      Spain: {
        cities: {
          Valencia: {
            values: []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to filter by its keys but when it comes to placing the objects in the right place (e.g by same Continent) I couldn't get it working.

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, total) => {
  const continentFilter = total.location.find(s => s.type === 'Continent')

  acc[continentFilter.name] = {
    // ...
  }
  return acc
}, {})


console.log(result)
// {
//  Africa: { ... },
//  Europe: { ... }
// }
```

UPDATE:

- The type is always 'Continent', 'Country', or 'City'
- Some Continents/Countries might not have a City
- The goal is to organize by `Continent`, then by `Country` and `City`

Comment: Are these always organized this way? E.g. `[Continent, Country, City]`?

Comment: yes. The type is always one of those.

Comment: But what I meant to ask, are they in that specific order?

Comment: no. in some continents we might not have a city. I'll add some more details to the question. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array for the nested properties which are not given by the location arrays (maybe there could be the key instead of unused `type`).

Then iterate the array and create a nested structure. At the end apply the values.

For unsorted location sort it in advance.

```js
const
    data = [{ location: [{ name: 'Angola', type: 'Country' }, { name: 'Luanda', type: 'City' }, { name: 'Africa', type: 'Continent' }], values: [] }, { location: [{ name: 'Europe', type: 'Continent' }, { name: 'Italy', type: 'Country' }, { name: 'Rome', type: 'City' }], values: [] }, { location: [{ name: 'Europe',type: 'Continent' }, { name: 'Spain', type: 'Country' },  { name: 'Valencia', type: 'City' }], values: [] }];
    levels = ['countries', 'cities'],
    result = data.reduce((r, { location, values }) => {
        const
            order = { Continent: 1, Country: 2, City: 3 },
            temp = location
                .sort((a, b) => order[a.type] - order[b.type])
                .reduce((o, { name }, i) => {
                    o[name] ??= {};
                    return levels[i]
                        ? (o[name][levels[i]] ??= {})
                        : o[name];            
                }, r);

        (temp.values ??= []).push(...values);
        return r;
    }, {});
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is great thanks @Nina. What would be the alternative (without nulish coalescing) for o[name] ??= {}; ?

Comment: you could take the logical OR, like `o[name] = o[name] || {};`.

Comment: There's an issue with this approach. If we change the order of the data to [{ name: "Luanda", type: "City" }, { name: "Angola", type: "Country" }, { name: "Africa", type: "Continent" }]. So we sort the type in the opposite way, the result would be wrong. it would say 'Africa' is a city. If we revert the `levels` array, it will give also the reverted order. The order should be by Continent, Country, City

Comment: It worked! Don't want to push my luck so far but, how would I add `values` as a sibling of `countries` and `cities`? Instead as just in the innermost node. Thanks in advance

Comment: with a better data structure ...? (jk) with the given structure take a shorter location array with only the wanted depth and then you get values at the level (this works). or take an object with a level index  and an array of values ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. I'm sure it can be improved.

```js
const data = [{
  location: [{
      name: 'Africa',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Angola',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Luanda',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}, {
  location: [{
      name: 'Europe',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Italy',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Rome',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}, {
  location: [{
      name: 'Europe',
      type: 'Continent'
    },
    {
      name: 'Spain',
      type: 'Country'
    },
    {
      name: 'Valencia',
      type: 'City'
    }
  ],
  values: []
}];

function countryDataToStructuredObject(data){
  let countryData = { };
  data.map(a => { 
    countryData[a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Continent').name] = {};
    countryData[a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Continent').name]['countries'] = {};
    countryData[a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Continent').name]['countries'][a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Country').name] = {};
    countryData[a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Continent').name]['countries'][a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Country').name]['cities'] = {};
    countryData[a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Continent').name]['countries'][a.location.find(x => x.type == 'Country').name]['cities'][a.location.find(x => x.type == 'City').name] = { values: a.values };
  });
  return countryData;
}

console.log(countryDataToStructuredObject(data));
```

Comment: why not improve it?

Comment: I went with a verbose, easy to follow along approach. I think your approach is far better, but maybe less understandable for somebody who is new to JavaScript.